# JavaScript on Onchange event from picklist

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am working on VF page - when I change the value of a picklist field then my pageblock table will show.

VF code

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="AllObjectCtrl">
<apex:form>
   <apex:pageBlock title="All Objects in Org">
       <apex:pageBlockSection> 
           <apex:selectList value="{!objectName}" size="1">
               <apex:selectOptions value="{!Name}">
                   <apex:actionSupport event="onChange" action="{!getrecords}" reRender="tableShow"/>
               </apex:selectOptions>           
           </apex:selectList>

           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selectedObj}" var="a" id="tableShow">
               <apex:column value="{!a}" headerValue="ID"/>
           </apex:pageBlockTable>
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem here?

Comment: The code is not working...

Comment: Can you please also post the `getrecords` method as well as other relevant backend code?

Answer (score 2):

you are using this thats why it is not running

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onChange" action="{!getrecords}" reRender="tableShow"/>
```

because the even="OnChange"is a java script finction and as java script is a case sensetive language so rather then using Capital c on onChnage use small "c" in onchange like this :

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getrecords}" reRender="tableShow"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The actionSupport should be a child of selectList. Example:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!objectName}" size="1">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onChange" action="{!getrecords}" reRender="tableShow"/>
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Name}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

You can use actionFunction and onchange selectList attribute. Example:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="getRecordsJS" action={!getrecords} reRender="tableShow"/> 

<apex:selectList value="{!objectName}" size="1" onchange="getRecordsJS();">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Name}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Torsen's answer should resolve your problem, but if there would be still something wrong, make sure to **always** add the `<apex:pagemessages />` somewhere in the page, in development phase. Rerender errors are sometimes hard to debug and the reasons might be catchy, like - nothing happens when any required field is not filled, nothing happens when you populate picklist from `set` etc...